# Android, Cant access Tab Item class

Tags: android

I am trying to add Tab items to a tab layout. My issue is that when I add a Tab Item in xml, android studio cannot not find the class. I have the support library imported and I can access Tab Layout. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use TabLayout, not TableLayout